# Return to Campaign on AC: Rogue

Tags: assassins-creed-rogue

I finished a story-only play through of Assassin's Creed: Rogue, and want to go back and finish everything. How can i do this? Do i need to start over again to get 100% Sync on my memories?

Answer (score 3):

Just wait for the credits to roll over (not possible to skip, unfortunately, and they are quite long) and you should be able to continue getting to your 100%.

After you're in freeplay mode you can select memories to replay in escape menu, as far as I remember.